# Multiple *.txt files watch through FileWatcher c#

Tags: c#

I tried to monitor the directory with FileWatcher. When several files changed I must insert added data of txt files into database. But it does not work after the second attempt. So, Windows shows such message: this file is used by another program. I think that it relates to the ReaderWriterLockSlim class which used in this code. Please, suppose your solutions. I am working with ASP.NET MVC, not Windows Forms App.
Here the code

```
public class MultiWatcher : IDisposable
{
    private List<string> filePaths;
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim rwlock;
    private System.Timers.Timer processTimer;
    private string watchedPath;
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    private int readLinesCount = 0;

    public MultiWatcher(string watchedPath)
    {
        filePaths = new List<string>();

        rwlock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        this.watchedPath = watchedPath;
        InitFileSystemWatcher();
    }

    private void InitFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_FileChanged);
        watcher.Error += Watcher_Error;
        watcher.Path = watchedPath;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void Watcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // Watcher crashed. Re-init.
        InitFileSystemWatcher();
    }



    private void Watcher_FileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            rwlock.EnterWriteLock();
            filePaths.Add(e.Name);

            if (processTimer == null)
            {
                // First file, start timer.
                processTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
                processTimer.Elapsed += ProcessQueue;
                processTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                // Subsequent file, reset timer.
                processTimer.Stop();
                processTimer.Start();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            rwlock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    private void ProcessQueue(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Processing queue, " + filePaths.Count + " files created:");
            rwlock.EnterReadLock();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                RecordEntry(filePath);  // try to insert txt file data into database
            }

            filePaths.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (processTimer != null)
            {
                processTimer.Stop();
                processTimer.Dispose();
                processTimer = null;
            }
            rwlock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    //insert txt file data into database
    private void RecordEntry(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            { 
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)))
                {
                    Data_access da = new Data_access();
                    readLinesCount = da.GetReadLinesCount(fileName);
                    int totalLinesCount = File.ReadAllLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)).Length;

                    int newLinesCount = totalLinesCount - readLinesCount;

                    //var fileByLine = File.ReadLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/101_Sensors.txt")).Last();
                    var fileByLine = File.ReadLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)).Skip(readLinesCount).Take(newLinesCount);
                    var each = fileByLine.Select(l => l.Split('_'));
                    string[] parsedFileContent = new string[fileByLine.Count()];
                    foreach (var item in fileByLine)
                    {
                        parsedFileContent = item.Split('_');
                        da.AddParams(parsedFileContent, totalLinesCount, fileName);
                    }
                    da.SetReadLinesCount(totalLinesCount, fileName);
                }
            }
            //using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)))
            //{
            //    int totallinesCount = File.ReadAllLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)).Length;
            //    int newLinesCount = totallinesCount - readLinesCount;

            //    //var fileByLine = File.ReadLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Content/101_Sensors.txt")).Last();
            //    var fileByLine = File.ReadLines(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Sensors/" + fileName)).Skip(readLinesCount).Take(newLinesCount);
            //    var each = fileByLine.Select(l => l.Split('_'));
            //    string[] parsedFileContent = new string[fileByLine.Count()];
            //    foreach (var item in fileByLine)
            //    {
            //        parsedFileContent = item.Split('_');
            //        da.AddParams(parsedFileContent, totallinesCount, fileName, readLinesCount);
            //    }
            //}
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (rwlock != null)
            {
                rwlock.Dispose();
                rwlock = null;
            }
            if (watcher != null)
            {
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                watcher.Dispose();
                watcher = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you, please, specify at least, where the problem occurs?

Comment: the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` does not seem to do anything here, at least not moderating file system access (you enter a write lock, start a timer that will do something in a second, then immediately release the lock). Is there another *process* accessing the files, which is not under your control? you may need to implement a wait+retry mechanism when a file is locked "from outside".

Comment: Windys, I try to monitor a directory. When multiple txt files changed, my program must insert into database data parsed from changed txt files. So, to do that I modify for example 4 txt files manually from Windows and   copy them to monitored directory. This FileWatcher calls RecordEntry method that inserts txt file data into the database. It works once, second and at the third attempt it reveals me message: this file is used by another program.

Comment: Have You got any solutions of monitoring the directory and insert file data into the database? I allocated inserting in another Stream -> FIleStream. And when we use "using(){}" it closes file and streamReader automatically, yes? But what program or process proceeds to use my txt files?